# "Exported type should have comment or be unexported" golang VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, golint

I tried this code in Go:

```
type Agent struct {
    name string    // Not exported
    categoryId int // Not exported
}
```

And VS Code reports the following *problem*:

> exported type Agent should have comment or be unexported

The warning is kind of annoying. So I have the following questions:

- How to get rid of it?
- What comment should I put?
- Is there any *default* comment template for this?

It asks me to put a comment but it does not offer me to add one by default.

Comment: Add a comment or do not run golint.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Just add a comment above it, starting with the name of your type (or function, method etc.) like this:

```
// Agent is ...
type Agent struct {
   name string
   categoryId int
}
```

This linter error is caused by your `Agent` type being exported, even if its attributes are not. To not export your type, define it in lowercase like such:

```
type agent struct {
   name string
   categoryId int
}
```

The reason why your linter complains about this is that godoc uses those comments to automatically generate documentation for your projects. You can find many examples of such documented Go projects at [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus?tab=doc).

If you upload one of your Go projects to GitHub for example, pkg.go.dev will automatically generate a documentation for you using those comments. You can even add runnable code examples and many other things, as shown on [go-doc tricks](https://godoc.org/github.com/fluhus/godoc-tricks).

Comment: it can be anything? free text?

Comment: It has to start with your type name, like in my example.

Comment: That's the only limitation

Comment: After some time programming in Go this type of thing turns more natural...
To be more about it, go to the "Effective Go" in the documentation, in resume, the idea is to be more clear and write idiomatic Go code.

Thanks for sharing the tips

Comment: @Ullaakut Seems like it doesn't "have to" start with the _type name_, but **IF** it does - it may be useful.  Here is a quote from the [documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#commentary): "_If every doc comment begins with the name of the item it describes, you can use the doc subcommand of the go tool and run the output through grep._" And then it gives an example of how it may be useful etc. So it's not a _restriction_, but rather a useful _option_.

Answer (score 45):

### Who

This warning is produced by the official [*linter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) for Go source code - [***golint***](https://github.com/golang/lint). *Golint* is used as the *default* linter by the [*Go extension*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Go) in Visual Studio Code editor.

---

### Why

To understand the ***reason*** why *golint* showed that warning, we can refer to the official Go documentation related to comments - ["Go Doc Comments"](https://go.dev/doc/comment) (quote):

> Every exported (*capitalized*) name in a program should have a doc comment.

But this indeed *can* be [annoying](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/389) if you tend to write *self-documenting* code (i.e. the intention is clear from a *name* itself etc).

---

## Solution

Besides the already proposed [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004330/814702), what you can do is start using the alternative and more advanced [*golangci-lint*](https://golangci-lint.run/) which is a Go linters *aggregator*. It has *golint* [disabled by default](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters#disabled-by-default-linters--e--enable), so this annoying warning  about missing *doc comments* will not be triggered. Of course you can turn this warning on if you want by using the related [flags](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/) (see `--exclude strings` and `--exclude-use-default`).

The possibility to change the linter is also mentioned on the description page of Go extension:

[image]

---

### How to change lint tool for the Go Extension in VS Code

In order to change lint tool in VS Code perform the following steps.

**1)** Choose the "*Configure Extension Setting*s" in the Go Extension's management menu:

[image]

**2)** Select "golangci-lint" from the related drop-down list:

[image]

**3)** To prevent VS Code from freezing as a result of using this powerful linter, add the `--fast` flag as described in the ["Editor Integration"](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#editor-integration) instructions.

To do that, you need to navigate to the Go Extension configuration page (as in step 1), open the `settings.json` file and add the related configuration as shown on the below screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**NB!** Here is a quote from the "*golangci-lint*" [FAQ](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#faq):

> **Why running with --fast is slow on the first run?**
> Because the first run caches type information. All subsequent runs will be fast.
> Usually this options is used during development on local machine and compilation was already performed.

Comment: Golangci-lint is a wrapper of multiple linters. What you're doing here is disabling it running golint entirely.

Comment: @dfarrell07 Yes, *golangci-lint* is a Go linters **aggregator**. So what's the problem? "Disabling it running golint entirely" -  what do you mean, for the case when a lack of comments should be reported? It **solves** the problem in question, the one the OP were asking - so how is it wrong, when even Microsoft developers (the authors of the VS Code Go extension) also directly mention it. What's your problem? Those `--exclude` and `--exclude-use-default` flags ARE MEANT just for such cases, to make developers' lives easier.

Comment: I will update my answer to mention that golang-ci is a Go linters *aggregator* to make it more formal.

Comment: You say "It has the default settings not to warn about those missing doc comments", and I'm saying that's missleading. It doesn't ignore them, it just doesn't run golint.

Comment: @dfarrell07 If specifying **how exactly** _golangci_ achieves this not reporting the missing doc comments issue - then you're right. I will update my answer accordingly to mention this moment. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Clarification that Golint stops being run, not just warning disabled, is my key issue. That's clear in your latest version. Thanks!

Comment: The current version of https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html doesn't say anything about comments on exports, that seems to have moved to https://go.dev/doc/comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by simply adding comment above the function name.

Example below:

```
//ArrayBasic1 is the function for calculating array
func ArrayBasic1() {
  x := [5]int{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30}
  fmt.Println("value from arraybasic1", x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Officially, this is a language lint recommendation that should not be disabled. There has been a long discussion around that since 2016, but it seems stuck.

If you want to do it anyway, the `--exclude` accepts regex values. So, you can run your command line lint ignoring that particular rule.

```
golangci-lint run --exclude="\bexported \w+ (\S*['.]*)([a-zA-Z'.*]*) should have comment or be unexported\b"
```